# How to convert text content in a buffer to location list in vim?

Tags: vim

For example, I have below content in a buffer 2,

```
/works/a.txt
/works/b.c
/works/c.java
```

when I tried `:lgetbuffer 2` and `:lopen` to open location list, it looks like

```
|| /works/a.txt
|| /works/b.c
|| /works/c.java
```

And pressing enter on the first item does not help me open `/works/a.txt`.

Comment: Just FYI, you may get better coverage on this question on the official vi/vim SE: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I figured out of this, post my own answer here for others who has same requirement.

Every line in the buffer needs to be:

```
<file_name>:<line_number>:<content_of_the_line>
```

So if the buffer looks like below, it will be fine.

```
/works/a.txt:1:1
/works/b.c:1:1
/works/c.java:1:1
```